# Newly created user not able to login from RockMongo

Tags: mongodb, rockmongo, database, nosql

here is sample user which I have created by mongo shell,

```
{
   "_id": "admin.root",
   "user": "root",
   "db": "admin",
   "credentials": {
     "MONGODB-CR": "81e657aa9d80e314f75b9271216262fc" 
  },
   "roles": [
     {
       "role": "readWriteAnyDatabase",
       "db": "admin" 
    },
     {
       "role": "userAdminAnyDatabase",
       "db": "admin" 
    },
     {
       "role": "dbAdminAnyDatabase",
       "db": "admin" 
    },
     {
       "role": "clusterAdmin",
       "db": "admin" 
    } 
  ] 
}
```

Can you please help me how we can add new user for rock mongo ?